# Redis or Memcache for caching AVPs ?

Tags: performance, caching, redis, memcached, scalability

i have a simple Question, i think so.

I am a webdeveloper and want to cache some AVPs that i receive from "slow" webservices. 
Also i want to cache some AVPs from a Databases.

What would be the better in-memory database for caching redis or memcache?

Important for me is scalability and performance.

Comment: ... and an AVP is ... ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVP

Comment: Both memcached and redis can provide scalability and performance. Pick the one you are the most comfortable with.

Comment: AVP is Attribute Value Pair -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute%E2%80%93value_pair

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS#Attribute_value_pairs